# Why am getting error like this in view page

Tags: codeigniter

```
CI_DB_mysql_result Object([conn_id] => Resource id #28[result_id] => Resource id #33[result_array] => Array ()[result_object] => Array()[custom_result_object] => Array()
[current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1[row_data] =>)
```

here is my model page

```
public function getProductsListByCategory1($limit, $start) 
            {                           
                        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
                        $this->db->select('image_path,tagline,category_id,product_id');
                        $this->db->where('category_id','1');
                        $query = $this->db->get("tb1_bl_products order by tagline");
                        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
                        {
                            foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
                            {
                                $data[] = $row;
                            }
                        return $data;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return array();     
                        }
            }
```

Comment: CI_DB_mysql_result Object([conn_id] => Resource id #28[result_id] => Resource id #33[result_array] => Array ()[result_object] => Array()[custom_result_object] => Array()
[current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1[row_data] =>)

Comment: this is not an error. You are doing print_r some objects

Comment: ok then how can i hide this,because while loading the view page ,above statement are blinking for secs in header. then only styles are loading.

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: I don't think you can put your 'order by' in the ->get() method, You should be using ->order_by() method instead, And you don't need to build an array or do a foreach the result you're returning is effectively just like saying 'return $query->result();' Your foreach isn't doing anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

use `$query->result_array()` rather than `$query->result()`